# How do I merge array values?

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => H
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
    [5] =>
    [6] => F
    [7] => r
    [8] => i
    [9] => e
    [10] => n
    [11] => d
)
```

And wanted to merge the values of the array based on the keys and end up with a new array of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hell
    [1] => o
    [2] => Friend

)
```

Whats the best way of doing so with php?

Comment: Could you be more specific with what you mean by "based on the keys"?

Comment: What is so special about that "hell" :)

Comment: lol, to me that seems completely whimsical unless you want to split with spaces.

Comment: Could you explain the logic of your idea in the way that does not require AI or human ?)

Comment: Also, I think you mean based on values. The keys here would be indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to get the pieces you want (`range()`returns an array) and feed that array to [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to merge the array into a string. (`implode()` returns a string).

`implode(range(0,3))` should return `Hell`.

doing the previous does not remove the `ell` from their places. to remove other parts of the array, use [unset()](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20unset)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new array, and concatenate values of your previous array (from/to the index you want), you don't precise how you want to divide your words in your array (by that, I mean : why Hell o Friend?

```
<?php
    $arr_bis = array();
    $temp= '';
    $arr = array('h', 'e', 'y');
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $temp.=$value;
    }

    array_push($arr_bis, $temp);
?>
```

It is not a complete solution, just how I think it could be done!

Answer (score 0):

You could separate by words like this:

```
$input = Array('H','e','l','l','o','','!');

$merged = array();

$word = '';
foreach ($input as $k=>$v) {
    if (!empty($v)) {
        $word .= $v;
    } else {
        array_push($merged, $word);
        $word = '';
    }
}
array_push($merged, $word);

var_dump($merged);
```